# Need to get my divs side by side

Tags: css

I am just trying to get the image box to slide up next to the BBD logo and I can't seem to figure it out.

A bit new to css and floats, etc. Can anyone offer a suggestion???

I'm working off of a template, so didn't set up the css myself.

Thanks!

[link text](http://dreamtrampoline.com/bierman/index-slider2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to float both the  `div` with the bbd logo and the `div.slideshowgallery`. When both siblings are floated (left for example), they will be next to each other (if the width of the containing block permits it).

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion? I can give you that.

```
#sliderWrapper > div { float: left; }
```

Add this CSS and your divs will be side by side. Rounded corners and the background will break. To solve the background, add `<div class="clear"></div>` to the bottom of the `sliderWrapper` div. The rest... no idea.

Comment: or you could add overflow:hidden; to sliderWrapper to fix the backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

always remember to work with a wrap container with a specific width otherwise is very difficult, to make this with a elastic design.

and then just float both divs... ideally on the same side and spearate them with their own margins.